# PYTHON - Compare columns from different dataframes with condition, with for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, while-loop

I have 2 dataframe with numeric values. I want to compare each column (they have the same column_names), and if them all are equal, execute a condition (add 10 points to score). I have done it "manually", it works, but I don't like it that way. Let me show you:

score=0

<kbd>DATAFRAME 1</kbd>

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |

<kbd>DATAFRAME 2</kbd>

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |

So, if the values of each columns are equal, **score** will be score=score+10

```
score=0
if (df1['Column A'][0]==df2['Column A'][0])&(df1['Column B'][0]==df2['Column B'][0])&(df1['Column C'][0]==df2['Column C'][0])&(df1['Column D'][0]==df2['Column D'][0]):
    score=score+10
```

I want to do this but optimize it, like with a for loop or something like that. How could it be done? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pandas [equals](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) function.

Here is the simple implementation:

```
if df1.equals(df2):
    score += 10 
else:
    print("Columns are not equal")
```

Comment: I am not allowed :(

"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Answer (score 0):

Compare the values element by element, then check if you only have True per row and sum to find out how many rows satisfy the condition and finally multiply by 10:

```
>>> df1.eq(df2).all(axis=1).sum() * 10
10
```